# Xpath consuming to much CPU on Postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I have a problem with a production software eating all cpu from db server.

Software versions:

- PostgreSQL 9.1.6 64-bit
- Linux Kernel 2.6.32
- Red Hat 6.3

Hardware (virtual machine):

- 24 cores (same as physical host)
- 24 GB of ram

Actually this is the only virtual machine on the physical server. Vmware.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE doctable
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  lastupdateddate timestamp without time zone,
  mycolor character varying(255),
  myshade character varying(255),
  xmlstuff xml,
  CONSTRAINT doctable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Actual index:

```
CREATE INDEX doctable_shade_color_idx
  ON doctable
  USING btree
  (myshade  COLLATE pg_catalog."default", mycolor COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

The actual query:

```
SELECT XPATH($1, xmlstuff) FROM doctable WHERE myshade = $2 AND mycolor= $3;
```

The index is used correctly, but with undreds of calls per minute like this, the xpath function is eating CPU to 100%, slowing the server.

Also xml can be from few Kbytes to few megabytes.

I build an index on the most common path used, but I don't think an index here can be used. Am I wrong?

I cant access sources in the next weeks and load is increasing. There is something I can do?

Disk access is very low because all data is in ram. Maybe setting STORAGE EXTERNAL for xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the SQL part is working correctly as you say, but what happens is - the custom ($1) XPath expression is evaluated over N rows returned by WHERE. And as far as I know there's nothing in postgresql you can do. It just takes time to parse the xml and apply expression (which can be arbitrarily complicated).

In my opinion is just not a very good design, performance wise at least. Probably one way to remedy the situation would be to build a helper table (and keep it up-to-date somehow) with the most common XPath queries and pre-calculated results.

The query/stored proc would look something like:

`SELECT XPathResult From tblHelper WHERE XPathQuery = $1 and myshade = $2 AND mycolor= $3;`

Only if the XPathQuery was not pre-calculated then execute it. Indexes on all columns but XPathResult I guess, depending on your queries.

On the `doctable` I'd put INSERT/UPDATE triggers that would run the set of most common queries and insert them into helper table. And of course you'd have to run some long-running sproc to populate it the first time.

This is all hacky, but I don't see a better way at the moment. Hopefully someone else will come with better ideas :)

Comment: The design is ugly, I know. But sadly I cannot access sources, so query can be changed :-/

Comment: After long time and a lot of problems we finally get sources and decoded xml in tables. In real relational tables. So... problem solved. Your answer was good, accepting it to close end the question.